# How can docker downloading new image output log messages can be supressed?

Tags: docker, output

I have an automated setup to run some processes using docker. Sometimes, it uses a different version of the image, and docker downloads the new version. I would like to supress log messages regarding new image being downloaded to the end user and provide no useful information to him.

Is there any command line option for `docker run` in order to do so?

Do you have any other idea on how to accomplish this?

I looked into the documentation and help but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash redirection to accomplish this. like

> docker run -itd busybox >/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: Yeah, but then I supress any other log or error log, and cannot handle any failure. I would like to only supress download progress output.

Comment: In that case, probably redirect only the output and not the error

Comment: like `docker run -itd busybox >/dev/null`